# Pointer arthmetic confusion

Tags: c

I see the below code snippet always return 1 instead of 4 Not able to really make out what is wrong

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
   int a[4] = {1,2,3,4};
   int *p = a;

   p++;
   printf("%ld\n",(long int)(p-a));
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you assign a which points to the first element to the pointer p then increment  p points to 2 and if you again subtract a from it you're back at 1 ?!

Comment: What did you expect?? *p=a; p++; p-a;..

Comment: why do you expect 4?

Comment: Try this instead: printf("%ld\n",(long int)((char *)p-(char *)a));

Comment: You calculating how many blocks apart the pointer and the array are, not how many bytes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the basics of pointer arithmetic. When you have:

```
int a[4] = {0};
int *p = a;
```

when you do `p++` - compiler automatically increases `p`
with four bytes (in case size of integer is four).
Same happens with subtraction if you subtract 1
from `p` compiler will automatically subtract four bytes.
But to more precisely answer your question it seems
`-` operator when applied to pointer types
divides result on size of element type to which
pointer points to.